# How to install PyCharm on Ubuntu Mate (Raspberry Pi3)?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install PyCharm on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Mate. But I don't understand the error message I get.

First I followed this tutorial : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-18-04/

it was just about writing `python sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`

I received this error `snap "pycharm-community" is not available on stable for this architecture (armhf) but exists on other architectures (amd64).`

Secondly I tried another tutorial using Umake. https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I received this error `Keyerror : 'armhf'`.

What does it mean? It is possible to install Pycharm on a raspberry running Ubuntu Mate?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to install PyCharm on a Raspberry Pi. The `armhf` error means that the RPi hardware (processor) is not supported by PyCharm.

**However:** PyCharm does support remote development (after a fashion) on the RPi, but you will have to install PyCharm on a system that runs on supported hardware (e.g. Intel). PyCharm/JetBrains has a [tutorial (several actually) that may help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-development-on-raspberry-pi.html) you. PyCharm's support for Raspberry Pi requires that a series of "helper apps" be installed on your RPi; these "helper apps" facilitate communication and remote control between your development system (Intel-based), and your target system (RPi). There are quite a few of these "helper apps" installed during the process of configuring PyCharm to do remote development on the RPi.

You may wish to [review this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83263/is-there-an-ide-that-fully-supports-remote-development-and-remote-host-execut) to learn about other options for Python development on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I was searching for the exact same question and fond this answer: https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2019/09/12/installing-pycharm-on-raspberry-pi

I have tested it on Twister OS 1.8.2(based on raspberry pi OS) and Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and it works without issues.

TL;DR go to https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux

1. Download pycharm
2. Extract and run `pycharm.sh` from the bin folder.

Comment: Link only answers is likely to get deleted. Please add an answer that can stand for itself.